# Extract specifications from Spock specs

Tags: grails, spock

Is there a way to obtain specifications (filtering the code) from my Spock tests printed in a file?

For example, for the following spec:

```
class CarSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def 'it should not retrieve deleted cars'() {
        given: 'a car'
            def car = new Car(uniqueName: 'carName')
            car.save()
        when: 'I delete the car'
            car.delete()
        then: 'it shouldn't find me the car on the DB'
            Car.find { uniqueName == 'carName' } == null
    }
}
```

should print something like:

```
CarSpec
    it should not retrieve deleted cars
        given a car
        when I delete the car
        then it shouldn't find me the car on the DB
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use one of the available third-party plugins (e.g. https://github.com/damage-control/report), or write your own Spock extension (see https://github.com/spockframework/smarter-testing-with-spock/tree/master/src/test/groovy/extension/custom).

Comment: Do you have any instructions on how to use damage-control plugin? the README file doesn't seem clear enough.

Comment: I notice you are the author of `spock.lang.@Issue` - is there an easy way of making the damage control report include the link on the report?

Comment: You'd have to ask the author of Damage Control Report.